# How to create a timeline with LaTeX?

Tags: latex, tex, timeline

In history-books you often have timeline, where events and periods are marked on a line in the correct relative distance to each other. How is it possible to create something similar in LaTeX?

Comment: here my answer : 

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183046/how-do-i-develop-a-complex-time-line/227149#227149

I hope It could help

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [tikz](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package seems to have what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[snake=zigzag, line before snake = 5mm, line after snake = 5mm]
    % draw horizontal line   
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[snake] (2,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw (4,0) -- (5,0);
    \draw[snake] (5,0) -- (7,0);

    % draw vertical lines
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,4,5,7}
      \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

    % draw nodes
    \draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 0 $} node[above=3pt] {$   $};
    \draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 1 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 10 $};
    \draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 2 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 20 $};
    \draw (3,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
    \draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 5 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 50 $};
    \draw (5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 6 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 60 $};
    \draw (6,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
    \draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$ n $} node[above=3pt] {$ 10n $};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm not too expert with tikz, but this does give a good timeline, which looks like:

[image]

Comment: The output looks good. The syntax is not as simple as I hoped, but I think I can create some commands to simplify the stuff. Thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: can we label the timeline on the lefthand side? like numbers

Answer (score 87):

There is a new [chronology.sty](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chronology/chronology.sty) by [Levi Wiseman](https://web.archive.org/web/20110830214835/http://codeaholic.com/Portfolio/Design/LaTeX/Chronology).  The [documentation](http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/macros/latex/contrib/chronology/chronology.pdf) (pdf) says:

> Most timeline packages and solutions for LATEX are used to convey a lot of information and are therefore designed vertically. If you are just attempting to assign labels to dates, a more traditional timeline might be more appropriate. That's
>   what chronology is for.

Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1983}{2010}{3ex}[\textwidth]
\event{1984}{one}
\event[1985]{1986}{two}
\event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{three}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this output:

> [image: example output from chronology.sty]

Comment: It should be noted that this package appears to only support one timeline per document.  At least for me, I get the error "command \c@step already defined" when I try to have more than one.

Comment: I tried to modify the chronology.sty file in order to get a vertical timeline but didn't quite succeed. Is there a vertical version of it?

Comment: What package contains ```\textwidth```?

Comment: @KarlRichter try this [link](http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/macros/latex/contrib/chronology/chronology.pdf)

Comment: For those experiencing a "missing number" error on compiling this example, see the following question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233781/creating-a-timeline-with-chronology (remove `{3ex}`).

Comment: @highsciguy I succeeded with `\begin{turn}{90}` then the chonology and close with `\end{turn}`

Comment: it overlays the timeline on top of the text. any idea how we can solve this?

Comment: @Foad how about putting the timeline in a `float` environment?

Comment: documentation link is dead

Comment: @alper The Wayback Machine comes to our rescue https://web.archive.org/web/20191023080913/http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/macros/latex/contrib/chronology/chronology.pdf

Comment: I used this for a birth year timeline of my relatives and it works nicely. Now I just need to worry about them not wanting the info revealed!

Answer (score 30):

Also the package [chronosys](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chronosys) provides a nice solution. Here's an example from the user manual:

[image]

Comment: thanks! strange though, the guy who wrote the documentation keeps calling the timeline a "frieze" as if that is the same thing as a timeline. just putting that here in case anybody else reads the documentation.

Comment: @JonathanKomar it's from French frise, from medieval Latin frisium. It refers to a broad horizontal band of sculpted or painted decoration, or also a horizontal paper strip.

Answer (score 18):

Just an update.

The present TiKZ package will issue:
Package tikz Warning: Snakes have been superseded by
decorations. Please use the decoration libraries instead of the
snakes library on input line. . .

So the pertaining part of code has to be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%draw horizontal line
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=5mm, post length=5mm}] (2,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (4,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=5mm, post length=5mm}] (5,0) -- (7,0);

%draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,4,5,7}
\draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

%draw nodes
\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 0 $} node[above=3pt] {$   $};
\draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 1 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 10 $};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 2 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 20 $};
\draw (3,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 5 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 50 $};
\draw (5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 6 $} node[above=3pt] {$ 60 $};
\draw (6,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
\draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$ n $} node[above=3pt] {$ 10n $};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

HTH

Comment: I think this has now become: `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}`. Also, do `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` if you want a tightly cropped picture to insert in another document.

Answer (score 16):

[Tim Storer](http://www.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~tws/) wrote a more flexible and nicer looking [`timeline.sty`](http://web.archive.org/web/20070717115907/http://www.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~tws/tools/latex/timeline.zip) (Internet Archive Wayback Machine link, as original is gone).  In addition, the line is horizontal rather than vertical.  So for instance:

```
\begin{timeline}{2008}{2010}{50}{250}
  \MonthAndYearEvent{4}{2008}{First Podcast}
  \MonthAndYearEvent{7}{2008}{Private Beta}
  \MonthAndYearEvent{9}{2008}{Public Beta}
  \YearEvent{2009}{IPO?}
\end{timeline}
```

produces a timeline that looks like this:

```
2008                              2010
 · · April, 2008 First Podcast    ·
       · July, 2008 Private Beta
           · September, 2008 Public Beta
                · 2009 IPO?
```

Personally, I find this a more pleasing solution than the other answers.  But I also find myself modifying the code to get something closer to what I think a timeline should look like.  So there's not definitive solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, I prefer `tikz` guided solution, because it gives you more freedom. Secondly, I'm not posting anything totally new. It is obviously similar to Zoe Gagnon's answer, because he showed the way.

I needed some year timeline and it took me some time (what a surprise!) to do it, so I'm sharing the results. I hope you'll like it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\newlength\yearposx
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.57] % timeline 1990-2010->
    % define coordinates (begin, used, end, arrow)
    \foreach \x in {1990,1992,2000,2002,2004,2005,2008,2009,2010,2011}{
        \pgfmathsetlength\yearposx{(\x-1990)*1cm};
        \coordinate (y\x)   at (\yearposx,0);
        \coordinate (y\x t) at (\yearposx,+3pt);
        \coordinate (y\x b) at (\yearposx,-3pt);
    }
    % draw horizontal line with arrow
    \draw [->] (y1990) -- (y2011);
    % draw ticks
   \foreach \x in {1992,2000,2002,2004,2005,2008,2009}
        \draw (y\x t) -- (y\x b);
    % annotate
    \foreach \x in {1992,2002,2005,2009}
        \node at (y\x) [below=3pt] {\x};
    \foreach \x in {2000,2004,2008}
        \node at (y\x) [above=3pt] {\x};
    \begin{comment}
    % for use in beamer class
    \only<2>    {\fill      (y1992) circle (5pt);}
    \only<3-5>  {\fill      (y2000) circle (5pt);}
    \only<4-5>  {\fill      (y2002) circle (5pt);}
    \only<5>    {\fill[red] (y2004) circle (5pt);}
    \only<6>    {\fill      (y2005) circle (5pt);}
    \only<7>    {\fill[red] (y2005) circle (5pt);}
    \only<8-11> {\fill      (y2008) circle (5pt);}
    \only<11>   {\fill      (y2009) circle (5pt);}
    \end{comment}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it's tailored to beamer presentation (select part and also scale option), but if you really want to test it in a presentation, then you should move `\newlength\yearposx` outside of the frame definition, because otherwise you'll get error veritably stating that command `\yearposx` is already defined (unless you remove the selection part and any other frame-splitting commands from your frame).

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing: I've added a preamble to code and an image of the output, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @PatrickT: Any improvements in the answers are always welcomed, so obviously I cannot mind. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is [timeline.sty](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/timeline/timeline.sty) floating around.

The syntax is simpler than using tikz:

```
%%% In LaTeX:
%%% \begin{timeline}{length}(start,stop)
%%%   .
%%%   .
%%%   .
%%% \end{timeline}
%%%
%%% in plain TeX
%%% \timeline{length}(start,stop)
%%%   .
%%%   .
%%%   .
%%% \endtimeline
%%% in between the two, we may have:
%%% \item{date}{description}
%%% \item[sortkey]{date}{description}
%%% \optrule
%%%
%%% the options to timeline are:
%%%      length The amount of vertical space that the timeline should
%%%                use.
%%%      (start,stop) indicate the range of the timeline. All dates or
%%%                sortkeys should lie in the range [start,stop]
%%%
%%% \item without the sort key expects date to be a number (such as a
%%%      year).
%%% \item with the sort key expects the sort key to be a number; date
%%%      can be anything. This can be used for log scale time lines
%%%      or dates that include months or days.
%%% putting \optrule inside of the timeline environment will cause a
%%%      vertical rule to be drawn down the center of the timeline.
```

I've used python's datetime.data.toordinal to convert dates to 'sort keys' in the context of the package.

Comment: The link is dead, here is a github repo with a similar name : https://github.com/ArneMeier/timeline

The syntax is a bit different.

Answer (score 4):

I have been struggling to find a proper way to create a timeline, which I could finally do with this modification. Usually while creating a timeline the problem was that I could not add a text to explain each date clearly with a longer text. I modified and further utilized @Zoe Gagnon's latex script. Please feel free to see the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % draw horizontal line   
        \draw (-5,0) -- (6,0);
    
    
    % draw vertical lines
    \foreach \x in {-5,-4,-3,-2, -1,0,1,2}
    \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
    
    % draw nodes
    \draw (-5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 0 $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
    \draw (-4,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 1 $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45}
            All individuals vote
        \end{turn}$};
    \draw (-3,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 2 $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45} 
        Policy vector decided
        \end{turn}$};
    \draw (-2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 3 $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45}  Becoming a bureaucrat \end{turn} $};
    \draw (-1,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 4 $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45} Bureaucrats' effort choice \end{turn}$};
    \draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 5 $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45} Tax evasion decision made \end{turn}$};
    \draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {$  6$} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45} $p(x_{t})$ tax evaders caught \end{turn}$};
    \draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ 7 $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45} $q_{t}$ shirking bureaucrats \end{turn}$};
            \draw (3,0) node[below=3pt] {$ $} node[above=3pt] {$\begin{turn}{45} Public service provided  \end{turn}   $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Longer texts are not allowed, unfortunately. It will look like this:

[image: visual depiction of the timeline above]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for UML sequence diagrams, you might be interested in [pkf-umlsd](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/), which is based on TiKZ. Nice demos can be found [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-umlsd/).

Comment: No, I was more interested in a timeline like in a history-book. But thanks nevertheless, UML-diagrams in LaTeX may come up too in another project.

Answer (score 1):

It was a struggle to find a proper way to create a stylish timeline, but with a little bit of imagination and the TikZ package, I have created the following timeline. I have created two TikZ diagrams that can be used depending on the person's preference. In each case, the code is straightforward once you understand what is happening (additional comments were added to help). P.S. One needs to adjust the diagram depending on the requirements. Hope this will help!

```
\documentclass{article}

%Load necesary libraries
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

%Straight Timeline
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(0,-3.5)}]

  % Starting point at (0,0) on the page
  \coordinate (start) at (0,0);

  % Draw the first line: 25 degrees, 9cm length
  \draw[color = blue!40, line join=round, line cap=round, shading angle=25, opacity=0.5, top color=blue!10, bottom color=blue!60] (start) -- ++(-30:9cm) coordinate (end1); 

  % Draw the second line: -20 degrees, 9.5cm length
  \draw[color = blue!40, line join=round, line cap=round, shading angle=-20, opacity=0.5, top color=blue!10, bottom color=blue!60] (start) -- ++(-26:9.5cm) coordinate (end2);

  % Fill the space between the lines with blue and reduced opacity
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (start) -- (end1) -- (end2) -- cycle;
    \shade[bottom color=blue!10, top color=blue!60, opacity=0.5] (start) rectangle (end2|-end1);
  \end{scope}

  % Draw ovals at the starting point
  \draw[color = red, fill = red, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] (start) ++(-28:0.3cm) ellipse [x radius=0.05cm, y radius=0.012cm];
  \draw[color = orange, fill = orange, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] (start) ++(-28:2.2cm) ellipse [x radius=0.115cm, y radius=0.055cm];
  \draw[color = yellow, fill = yellow, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] (start) ++(-28:3.8cm) ellipse [x radius=0.18cm, y radius=0.11cm];
  \draw[color = green, fill = green, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] (start) ++(-27.95:6.2cm) ellipse [x radius=0.355cm, y radius=0.15cm];
  \draw[color = teal, fill = teal, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] (start) ++(-27.95:8cm) ellipse [x radius=0.42cm, y radius=0.21cm];

  % Draw ovals around the existing ovals
  \draw[color = red, line width = 0.005cm] (start) ++(-28:0.3cm) ellipse [x radius=0.05*1.5cm, y radius=0.012cm*1.5];
  \draw[color = orange, line width = 0.005cm] (start) ++(-28:2.2cm) ellipse [x radius=0.115cm*1.5, y radius=0.055cm*1.5];
  \draw[color = yellow, line width = 0.005cm] (start) ++(-28:3.8cm) ellipse [x radius=0.18cm*1.5, y radius=0.11cm*1.5];
  \draw[color = green, line width = 0.005cm] (start) ++(-27.95:6.2cm) ellipse [x radius=0.355cm*1.5, y radius=0.15cm*1.5];
  \draw[color = teal, line width = 0.005cm] (start) ++(-27.95:8cm) ellipse [x radius=0.42cm*1.3, y radius=0.21cm*1.3];

  % Draw perpendicular lines going up 3cm
  \draw[color = red, dashed, opacity=0.8] (start) ++(-28:0.3cm) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale = 0.9, color = red] {1997};
  \draw[color = orange, dashed, opacity=0.8] (start) ++(-28:2.2cm) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale=0.9, color = orange] {2004};
  \draw[color = yellow, dashed, opacity=0.8] (start) ++(-28:3.8cm) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale=0.9, color = yellow] {2005};
  \draw[color = green, dashed, opacity=0.8] (start) ++(-27.95:6.2cm) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale=0.9, color = green] {2007};
  \draw[color = teal, dashed, opacity=0.8] (start) ++(-27.95:8cm) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale=0.9, color = teal] {2010};

  % Add text under the years
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (1) at ($(start) + (-28:0.4cm) + (90:3cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (2) at ($(start) + (-28:0.4cm) + (90:2.8cm)$) {ipsum dolor};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (3) at ($(start) + (-28:2.3cm) + (90:3cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (4) at ($(start) + (-28:2.3cm) + (90:2.8cm)$) {ipsum dolor};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (5) at ($(start) + (-28:3.9cm) + (90:3cm)$) {Lorem ipsum};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (6) at ($(start) + (-28:3.9cm) + (90:2.8cm)$) {dolor sit};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (7) at ($(start) + (-28:3.9cm) + (90:2.6cm)$) {amet};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (8) at ($(start) + (-28:6.3cm) + (90:3cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (9) at ($(start) + (-28:6.3cm) + (90:2.8cm)$) {ipsum};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (10) at ($(start) + (-28:8.1cm) + (90:3cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (11) at ($(start) + (-28:8.1cm) + (90:2.8cm)$) {ipsum dolor};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 0.5] (12) at ($(start) + (-28:8.1cm) + (90:2.6cm)$) {sit amet};

  % Draw a box around the text nodes with the same opacity
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.8, fit={(1) (2)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.8, fit={(3) (4)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.8, fit={(5) (6) (7)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.8, fit={(8) (9)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.8, fit={(10) (11) (12)}] {};
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

%Curved Timeline
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(8,-3)}]

  %Define control points for the first S-shaped curve
  \coordinate (start) at (-4, 0);
  \coordinate (control1) at (6, -3);
  \coordinate (middle) at (0, -7);
  \coordinate (end1) at (-6, -11);

  % Draw the first S-shaped curve
  \draw(start) .. controls (control1) .. (middle) .. controls (middle) and (end1) .. (end1);

  % Optional: Add labels to the control points for the first curve
  %\filldraw [purple] (start) circle (2pt) node[below] {Start};
  %\filldraw [red] (control1) circle (2pt) node[left] {Control 1};
  %\filldraw [red] (middle) circle (2pt) node[above] {Middle};
  %\filldraw [red] (end1) circle (2pt) node[below] {End 1};

  % Define control points for the second S-shaped curve
  \coordinate (control3) at (8, -2.5);
  \coordinate (middle2) at (4, -6.5);
  \coordinate (end2) at (-3, -14);

  % Draw the second S-shaped curve with an arrow at the end
  \draw (start) .. controls (control3) .. (middle2) .. controls (middle2) and (end2) .. (end2);

  % Optional: Add labels to the control points for the second curve
  %\filldraw [blue] (control3) circle (2pt) node[right] {Control 3};
  %\filldraw [blue] (middle2) circle (2pt) node[below] {Middle 2};
  %\filldraw [blue] (end2) circle (2pt) node[above] {End 2};

  %General coordinates
  \coordinate (arrow1) at ($(end1) + (-1, +1)$);
  \coordinate (arrow2) at ($(end2) + (+1, -1)$);
  \coordinate (arrow3) at ($(arrow2) + (-5.3, 0)$);

  % Optional: Add labels to the control points for the arrow head
  %\filldraw [green] (arrow1) circle (2pt) node[below] {Arrow 1};
  %\filldraw [green] (arrow2) circle (2pt) node[above] {Arrow 2};
  %\filldraw [green] (arrow3) circle (2pt) node[above] {Arrow 3};

  %Draw the arrow head
  \draw (end1) -- (arrow1) -- (arrow3) -- (arrow2) -- (end2);

 %Shade the region between the two curves
 \begin{scope}
    \shade[bottom color=blue!10, top color=blue!60, opacity=0.8] 
      (arrow3) -- (arrow2) -- (end2) -- (middle2) .. controls (control3) .. (start) .. controls (control1) .. (middle) .. controls (middle) and (end1) .. (end1) -- (arrow1) -- (arrow3) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}

  % Define control points for the curved path
  \coordinate (pathControl) at ($(control1)!0.5!(control3)$);
  \coordinate (pathMiddle) at ($(middle)!0.5!(middle2)$);
  \coordinate (pathEnd) at (arrow3);
  \coordinate (pathEnd2) at ($(end1)!0.5!(end2)$);

  % Draw the curved path
  %\filldraw [yellow] (pathControl) circle (2pt) node[below] {Path Control};
  %\filldraw [yellow] (pathMiddle) circle (2pt) node[below] {Path Middle};
  %\filldraw [yellow] (pathEnd) circle (2pt) node[below] {Path End};
  %\filldraw [yellow] (pathEnd2) circle (2pt) node[below] {Path End2};
  %\draw[red] (start) .. controls (pathControl) .. (pathMiddle) .. controls (pathMiddle) and (pathEnd) .. (pathEnd2);
  %\draw[blue] (pathEnd2) -- (pathEnd);

  % Draw ovals at the starting point
  \draw[color = red, fill = red, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] ($(start) + (0.806, -0.2)$) ellipse [x radius=0.098cm, y radius=0.0225cm];
  \draw[color = orange, fill = orange, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] ($(start) + (4.2, -1.074)$) ellipse [x radius=0.436cm, y radius=0.155cm];
  \draw[color = yellow, fill = yellow, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] ($(start) + (6.85, -1.84)$) ellipse [x radius=0.77cm, y radius=0.27cm];
  \draw[color = green, fill = green, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] ($(start) + (9.23, -3.55)$) ellipse [x radius=1.135cm, y radius=0.5cm];
  \draw[color = teal, fill = teal, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] ($(start) + (7.31, -5.8)$) ellipse [x radius=1.22cm, y radius=0.65cm];
  \draw[color = blue, fill = blue, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] ($(start) + (5.02, -7.7)$) ellipse [x radius=1.72cm, y radius=0.75cm];
  \draw[color = purple, fill = purple, opacity = 0.8, line width=0.01cm] ($(start) + (2.1, -10.111)$) ellipse [x radius=2.36cm, y radius=0.95cm];

  % Draw ovals around the existing ovals with the same ratios
  \draw[color=red, line width=0.005cm] ($(start) + (0.806, -0.2)$) ellipse [x radius=0.098cm*1.575, y radius=0.0225cm*1.575];
  \draw[color=orange, line width=0.005cm] ($(start) + (4.2, -1.074)$) ellipse [x radius=0.436cm*1.5, y radius=0.155cm*1.5];
  \draw[color = yellow, line width = 0.005cm] ($(start) + (6.85, -1.84)$) ellipse [x radius=0.77cm*1.3, y radius=0.27cm*1.3];
  \draw[color = green, line width = 0.005cm] ($(start) +(9.23, -3.55)$) ellipse [x radius=1.135cm*1.3, y radius=0.5cm*1.3];
  \draw[color = teal, line width = 0.005cm] ($(start) + (7.31, -5.8)$) ellipse [x radius=1.22cm*1.3, y radius=0.65cm*1.3];
  \draw[color = blue, line width = 0.005cm] ($(start) + (5.02, -7.7)$) ellipse [x radius=1.72cm*1.25, y radius=0.75cm*1.25];
  \draw[color = purple, line width = 0.005cm] ($(start) + (2.1, -10.111)$) ellipse [x radius=2.36cm*1.2, y radius=0.95cm*1.2];

  % Draw perpendicular lines going up 3cm
  \draw[color = red, dashed, opacity = 1] ($(start) + (0.806, -0.2)$) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale = 0.9, color = red] {1997};
  \draw[color = orange, dashed, opacity = 1] ($(start) + (4.2, -1.074)$) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale = 0.9, color = orange] {2004};
  \draw[color = yellow, dashed, opacity = 1] ($(start) + (6.85, -1.84)$) -- ++(90:3.5cm) node[right, scale = 0.9, color = yellow] {2005};
  \draw[color = green, dashed, opacity = 1] ($(start) + (9.23, -3.55)$) -- ++(-90:3.5cm)  node[right, scale = 0.9, color = green] {2007};
  \draw[color = teal, dashed, opacity = 1] ($(start) + (7.31, -5.8)$) -- ++(-90:3.5cm) node[right, scale = 0.9, color = teal] {2010};
  \draw[color = blue, dashed, opacity = 1] ($(start) + (5.02, -7.7)$) -- ++(-90:4.5cm) node[right, scale = 0.9, color = blue] {2013};
  \draw[color = purple, dashed, opacity = 1] ($(start) + (2.1, -10.111)$) -- ++(-90:4.5cm) node[right, scale = 0.9, color = purple] {2017};

  % Add text under the years
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (1) at ($(start) + (0.87, -0.2)  + (90:2.8cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (2) at ($(start) + (0.87, -0.32)  + (90:2.4cm)$) {ipsum dolor};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (3) at ($(start) + (4.27, -1.074)  + (90:2.8cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (4) at ($(start) + (4.27, -1.074) + (90:2.4cm)$) {ipsum dolor};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (5) at ($(start) + (6.95, -1.84) + (90:2.8cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (6) at ($(start) + (6.95, -1.84)+ (90:2.4cm)$) {dolor sit};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (7) at ($(start) + (6.95, -1.84) + (90:2cm)$) {amet};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (8) at ($(start) + (9.38, -3.55) + (-90:2.4cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (9) at ($(start) + (9.38, -3.55) + (-90:2.8cm)$) {ipsum};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (10) at ($(start) + (7.36, -5.8) + (-90:2cm)$) {Lorem ipsum};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (11) at ($(start) + (7.36, -5.8) + (-90:2.4cm)$) {dolor sit};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (12) at ($(start) + (7.36, -5.8) + (-90:2.8cm)$) {amet};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (13) at ($(start) + (5.09, -7.7) + (-90:3cm)$) {Lorem ipsum};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (14) at ($(start) + (5.09, -7.7) + (-90:3.4cm)$) {dolor sit};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (15) at ($(start) + (5.09, -7.7) + (-90:3.8cm)$) {amet};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (16) at ($(start) + (2.25, -10.111) + (-90:3.4cm)$) {Lorem};
  \node[right, color = black, scale = 1] (17) at ($(start) + (2.25, -10.111) + (-90:3.8cm)$) {ipsum};

  % Draw a box around the text nodes with the same opacity
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.85, fit={(1) (2)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.85, fit={(3) (4)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.85, fit={(5) (6) (7)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.85, fit={(8) (9)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.85, fit={(10) (11) (12)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.85, fit={(13) (14) (15)}] {};
  \node[draw, line width = 0.005cm, rounded corners, scale = 0.85, fit={(16) (17)}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which looks likes:

[image: Straight Line Timeline]

[image: Curved Timeline]