# LaTex chronology change end of timeline

Tags: latex, timeline

I've got this example from [How to create a timeline with LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217834/how-to-create-a-timeline-with-latex?newreg=d5d53aaf6a014bda9555c93bf7597c74)

The only thing that bothers me is the little arrow at the end of the timeline.

Could someone tell me how to get the end of the line looking like the beginning?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
   \begin{document}
      \begin{chronology}[5]{1983}{2010}{\textwidth}
         \event{1984}{one}
         \event[1985]{1986}{two}
         \event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{three}
      \end{chronology}
   \end{document}
```

Problem:
[image]

Comment: Not that this doesn't fit for here, but you might find the more specialized LaTeX stackexchange a bit better of a fit for this sort of questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/